# How to make a xslt-tranformation with Saxon/C PHP-API

Tags: php, xml, xslt, saxon, saxon-c

I have a FrontController made in PHP with XSLT 1.0, i have installed the Saxon/C PHP-API to work with the XSLT 2.0. But now is the Problem, i must write the FrontController around the Saxon syntax.

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslDoc->load("../ressources/xslt/transform_article_partials_to_html.xslt");

$dir = __DIR__ . "/articles/" . $lang;
$filename = "{$rubrik}_{$seite}.html";
$filelist = scandir($dir, 1);

$proc->setParameter ("" , "articlePfad" , $filename);
$proc->setParameter("", "lang", $lang);

if($seite == null) {
  $filename = "{$rubrik}.html";
  if(in_array($filename, $filelist)) {
    $xmlDoc->load($dir . "/" . $filename);
  } else {
    echo "404";
  }
} else if(isset($seite) && isset($rubrik)){
  if(in_array($filename, $filelist)) {
    $xmlDoc->load($dir . "/" . $filename);
  } else {
    echo "404";
  }
}

$proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
```

Some sample code, what i do with the XSLT 1.0.

The Apache2 Error.log:

```
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/xsl (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xsl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/xsl.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xsl.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_class_entry)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'Saxon/C' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Jun 20 00:40:38.128672 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 892] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jun 20 00:40:38.130224 2019] [core:notice] [pid 892] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Jun 20 00:40:54.815341 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2692] [client 127.0.0.1:54472] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: saxonProc in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:40:54.815512 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2692] [client 127.0.0.1:54472] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function newXsltProcessor() on null in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/index.php(3): require()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:40:55.935485 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2691] [client 127.0.0.1:54474] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: saxonProc in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:40:55.935580 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2691] [client 127.0.0.1:54474] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function newXsltProcessor() on null in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/index.php(3): require()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:44:39.915201 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2719] [client 127.0.0.1:54508] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: saxonProc in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5, referer: http://localhost/Comelio%20Website/
[Thu Jun 20 00:44:39.915301 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2719] [client 127.0.0.1:54508] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function newXsltProcessor() on null in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/index.php(3): require()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5, referer: http://localhost/Comelio%20Website/
[Thu Jun 20 00:44:47.966250 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2692] [client 127.0.0.1:54510] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: saxonProc in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:44:47.966297 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2692] [client 127.0.0.1:54510] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function newXsltProcessor() on null in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/index.php(3): require()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:50:13.520374 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2691] [client 127.0.0.1:54528] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: saxonProc in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:50:13.520447 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2691] [client 127.0.0.1:54528] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function newXsltProcessor() on null in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/index.php(3): require()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:50:14.887942 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2806] [client 127.0.0.1:54530] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: saxonProc in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:50:14.888235 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2806] [client 127.0.0.1:54530] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function newXsltProcessor() on null in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/index.php(3): require()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:50:15.847351 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2693] [client 127.0.0.1:54532] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: saxonProc in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:50:15.874397 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2693] [client 127.0.0.1:54532] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function newXsltProcessor() on null in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/index.php(3): require()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:50:16.475331 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2690] [client 127.0.0.1:54534] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: saxonProc in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 00:50:16.475456 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2690] [client 127.0.0.1:54534] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function newXsltProcessor() on null in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/index.php(3): require()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 02:09:30.155871 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2719] [client 127.0.0.1:54596] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: saxonProc in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
[Thu Jun 20 02:09:30.156196 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2719] [client 127.0.0.1:54596] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function newXsltProcessor() on null in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/index.php(3): require()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/Comelio Website/comelio_com/FrontController.php on line 5
```

Comment: Have you looked at the examples Saxonica provides in https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.8/hec/samples/php/xsltExamples.php and http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/index.html#php-api? As for the input, in your given PHP code you load `.html` files? While libxslt/libxml I think has HTML parsing support, I am not sure Saxon-C has it too. So is the input document you have a well-formed XML document or are you processing HTML documents so far with XSLT 1 and PHP?

Comment: Yeah, its a FrontController or a Router, that parsing filenames for example "forschung_anleser.html" and the router makes this first to "forschung/anleser" in the URL. But the real task is to load the html-files and put together the header, the content and the footer. Like a small mini CMS. And it works all with XSLT 1.0, BUT the replace function dont exsists in the 1.0 only in the 2.0, we need to replace the path of images, css-files or javascript-files. And for that i need xslt 2.0.

Comment: PHPs `ext/xslt` has two features that offset the missing XSLT 2.0 support. You can register (static) PHP functions on the XSLTProcessor instance to call them from XSLT and with the function module from EXSLT you can wrap templates (including calls to PHP) in Xpath functions.

Comment: Where do you implement the `SaxonProcessor()`? Right now you appear to run [php/xsl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) which you are supposed to replace with the Saxon/C API. See @MartinHonnen's links.

Comment: @Parfait, I think you missed that the OP was showing "what I do with XSLT 1.0" and asking for an equivalent with Saxon and XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are using PHP's XSL class to supposedly run an XSLT 2.0 script. If you really do have the Saxon/C API installed, implement this in place of PHP's XSL class.

Consider the below, untested code as example using [online docs](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/index.html#php-api):

```
// INITIALIZE PROCESSOR
$saxonproc = new Saxon\SaxonProcessor();
$xsltProc = $saxonProc->newXsltProcessor();

// LOAD XSLT SCRIPT
$xslFile = "../ressources/xslt/transform_article_partials_to_html.xslt";
$xsltProc->compileFromFile($xslFile); 

// SET PARAMS
$dir = __DIR__ . "/articles/" . $lang;
$filename = "{$rubrik}_{$seite}.html";
$filelist = scandir($dir, 1);

$xdmvalue = $xsltProc->createAtomicValue($filename);
$xsltProc->setParameter("articlePfad", $xdmvalue);

$xdmvalue = $xsltProc->createAtomicValue($lang);
$xsltProc->setParameter("lang", $xdmvalue);

// LOAD SOURCE XML
if($seite == null) {
  $filename = "{$rubrik}.html";
  if(in_array($filename, $filelist)) {
    $xmlFile = $dir . "/" . $filename;    
  } else {
    echo "404";
    exit;
  }
} else if(isset($seite) && isset($rubrik)){
  if(in_array($filename, $filelist)) {
    $xmlFile = $dir . "/" . $filename;
  } else {
    echo "404";
  }
}

$xsltProc->setSourceFromFile($xmlFile);

// RUN TRANSFORMATION    
$result = $xsltProc->transformToString();

echo $result;

// RELEASE RESOURCES
$xsltProc->clearParameters();
$xsltProc->clearProperties();

unset($xsltProc);
unset($saxonproc);
```

Comment: I think you missed that the OP was showing "what I do with XSLT 1.0" and asking for an equivalent with Saxon and XSLT 2.0. But thanks for supplying an answer.

Comment: It dont works :/ But i think the Saxon/C extension is wrong installed or something, the samples are to dont working, the only thing that works is the version string from saxon.

Comment: Is there any information i nthe log file. Maybe try running your PHP script from the commandline or using gdb, which hopefully give some more information what is going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Hi, this error looks nothing like Saxon/C kind of errors. dom_node_class_entry is not from Saxon/C. Is it possible you can post your script. May post it on the Saxon/C help forum which we can link to this stackoverflow entry: https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon-c/boards

Comment: I have to replace some code, now it works! Thank you
I have post the Code.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help. So only `createAtomicValue` is real difference...interesting.

Comment: The `makeStringValue` method is only available on C++. In PHP we use `createAtomicValue` which implicitly converts the primitive typed value to the underlying XDM type object. See: http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/index.html#php-api

Answer (score 1):

So i changed the code and now it works!

```
<?php

// INITIALIZE PROCESSOR
$saxonProc = new Saxon\SaxonProcessor();
$xsltProc = $saxonProc->newXsltProcessor();

$lang = $_GET['lang'];
$rubrik = $_GET['rubrik'];
$seite = $_GET['seite'];

// LOAD XSLT SCRIPT
$xslFile = "../ressources/xslt/transform_article_partials_to_html.xslt";
$xsltProc->compileFromFile($xslFile); 

// SET PARAMS
$dir = __DIR__ . "/articles/" . $lang;
$filename = "{$rubrik}_{$seite}.html";
$filelist = scandir($dir, 1);

$xdmvalue = $saxonProc->createAtomicValue($filename);
$xsltProc->setParameter("articlePfad", $xdmvalue);

$xdmvalue = $saxonProc->createAtomicValue($lang);
$xsltProc->setParameter("lang", $xdmvalue);

// LOAD SOURCE XML
if($seite == null) {
  $filename = "{$rubrik}.html";
  if(in_array($filename, $filelist)) {
    $xmlFile = $dir . "/" . $filename;
    $xsltProc->setSourceFromFile($xmlFile);
  } else {
    echo "404";
    exit;
  }
} else if(isset($seite) && isset($rubrik)){
  if(in_array($filename, $filelist)) {
    $xmlFile = $dir . "/" . $filename;
    $xsltProc->setSourceFromFile($xmlFile);
  } else {
    echo "404";
  }
}

// RUN TRANSFORMATION    
$result = $xsltProc->transformToString();

echo $result;

// RELEASE RESOURCES
$xsltProc->clearParameters();
$xsltProc->clearProperties();

unset($xsltProc);
unset($saxonProc);

?>
```